# Difference between native null and managed null in C++/CX

Tags: c++-cx

I saw somewhere a fragment of code that looks like below.

The method `GetInfo` is called from a managed part of the project (written in C#) and it is a wrapper over a native method (written in C++).

What puzzles me is that if `bEverythingOK` is `false`, then the managed code receives a `nullptr`.

Could this be undefined behavior? If yes, what is the correct mode of returning a managed null (not an empty string)?

Is there any difference between managed null and native null? Should they be mixed together?

The native part:

```
String^ ConvertString(const std::string &nativeString)
{
    bool bEverythingOK = false;

    if(!bEverythingOK)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return ref new String(std::wstring(nativeString.begin(), nativeString.end()).c_str());
    }
}

String^ GetInfo()
{
    std::string info = NativeMethod();

    return ConvertString(info);
}
```

The managed part:

```
void ManagedMethod()
{
    string info = GetInfo();

    if (info == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Null string received.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something with the string
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You cannot return *anything* managed in C++/CX, it is not a language extension that supports managed code.  The syntax resembles C++/CLI but that's just a superficial similarity, Platform::String has nothing to do with System.String.  The glue in C++/CX is COM, the interop support for it built into the CLR takes care of converting your native nullptr to a managed null.

Comment: OK, this is the answer I needed: "the interop support takes care of converting your native nullptr to a managed null."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between managed and unmanaged `nullptr`. You are correct that if `bEverythingOK` is `false`, then the managed code receives a `nullptr`. There's nothing undefined about it yet. it all depends on what the caller does with the `nullptr`. (Which is code you did not include.)

Note that `Platform::String^` says that a `nullptr` string pointer must be treated as if it were a zero-length string, so in general, using `nullptr` where a `String^` is expected is safe and normal.

Comment: I added the native part, where the string is checked for `null`. It's just seems odd comparing checking the two nulls against each other.

Comment: Um, if `bEverythingOK` is true, then the function returns a non-null pointer.